# Number of rules in my fuzzy logic

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I have 6 variables with 4 membership functions such as "tiny,small,large,huge".

I tried to write the rules and came up with 200 rules but the combinations are killing me and it is still incomplete.

Can anyone tell me what is the exact number of rules that would cover every combination possible ?

For example one rule would be -
IF var1 IS huge AND var2 IS large AND var3 IS tiny AND var4 IS small AND var5 IS huge AND var6 IS huge THEN output IS small

Comment: Please give two examples of rules, so that we understand what you are trying to list.

Comment: Here's the generated output, and at the bottom of the page, the tiny program I wrote to generate it: https://gist.github.com/mjdominus/5775447

Comment: wow. awesome. thanks a ton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are $6$ variables, and each can be assigned one of $4$ adjectives, then the number of possible rules is $4 \times 4 \times 4 \times 4 \times 4 \times 4 = 4^6 = 4096$. (Assuming each rule is in the form of *IF a IS (adj) AND b IS (adj) ... THEN*)

Comment: omg... is there any tool available that would generate these for me? or is there any other way to do this?

Comment: @Dan, I see that MJD has generated a list of combinations in the comments above. However, note that you still would have to fill in manually each of these combinations to decide what the output should be. I think this is an indication that you should revise your method, rather than resorting to large truth tables.

Comment: Conceivably Dan could modify my program to emit the correct output value for each rule.

Comment: @MJD, but then he would already have a program which could decide what each output should be given the input, making the table unnecessary.

Comment: @George - yes you are right. I think this can only be less in number if i reduce the number of variables which is difficult. Manually deciding on the output is also a pain

Comment: Perhaps the system that consumes the rules is less programmable than a general-purpose programming language.  This sort of situation often arises in practice. For example, I have a number of programs written in general-purpose languages that generate instructions for the Unix `pic` diagram-drawing language, because although `pic` is ostensibly programmable to do what I want, it was a lot less trouble to use a real language to send simple instructions to `pic`, which for example does not support recursion.

Comment: It is instructive to observe that this is essentially the idea of a compiler. In principle, you can program every thing in machine language. In practice, you may prefer to write a specification in a higher-level language and have it compiled into the lower-level language.

Comment: Actually i am using a fuzzy logic package http://jfuzzylogic.sourceforge.net/html/index.html which uses an FCL file to generate the output. This requires to fill in the rules in the FCL file along with the variables and membership functions.

Comment: @MJD, I can see how such an approach may be useful, but in this case I feel that writing a compiler is far too much work, when an algorithm for determining it will be far faster and more space efficient.

Comment: @Dan, According to the [FAQ](http://jfuzzylogic.sourceforge.net/html/faq.html), "hard-coding the rules is highly discouraged". Instead, the site recommends that you add such rules using Java. (From "How can I programatically add rules with three or more antecedents?")

Comment: @George - I thought of editing the FCL file because writing 8-10 lines of java code for each of the 4096 rules is far more difficult and time consuming than just editing the FCL file.